# Outlook for Mac: How to Get Notifications that your Email has been Read/Opened

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook

I'm using the latest version of the Outlook desktop app on a Mac.

I cannot find the option, if there is one, to receive an email or notification that an email that has been read/opened by the receiver, which my boss says he receives on his Windows version of Outlook.

My options are very different than his due to working on a Mac so I don't know where to find how to do this after trying several places.

Answer (score 1):

#### I cannot find the option to receive an email or notification that an email that has been read/opened

You need to request a read receipt.

**Request a read receipt**

1. In Outlook 2016 for Mac, compose your message.
2. Select Options > Request Receipts > Request a Read Receipt.

   [image: Select Request Receipts on the Options ribbon]
3. Send your message.

Source [Request a read receipt or delivery notification in Outlook 2016 for Mac - Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/request-a-read-receipt-or-delivery-notification-in-outlook-2016-for-mac-2493ae0b-fba6-47f3-a5d5-ca0c0dbfe878)

In addition:

> This feature is available worldwide to:
>
> - Office 365 subscribers
> - Exchange mailboxes on Exchange Server 2010 SP2 and later
> - Users with Outlook version 15.35 (170610) and later

Source [Read Receipt feature not available in Outlook 2016 for MAC - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac-mso_o365b/read-receipt-feature-not-available-in-outlook-2016/08afc4da-945a-46cb-a08b-a923e7787f97)

Apparently all 3 conditions have to be satisfied.

Comment: Well thats why I couldn't find it – for some reason my Options menu bar doesn't have the Request Receipts icon? It has all of the others. I'm using version 16.9, so it looks like it should be enabled.

Comment: @alxmntrvl "This feature is available worldwide to:
Office 365 subscribers 
Exchange mailboxes on Exchange Server 2010 SP2 and later
Users with Outlook version 15.35 (170610) and later" apparently all 3 conditions have to be satisfied. See [Read Receipt feature not available in Outlook 2016 for MAC - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac-mso_o365b/read-receipt-feature-not-available-in-outlook-2016/08afc4da-945a-46cb-a08b-a923e7787f97)